# generators of affine transformation

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, mobius-transformation, finitely-generated, affine-varieties

I have to prove that the set $A$ of affine transformations $T(u)=au+b$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{F}$ and $a \ne 0$ forms a group under function composition and then I need to find a generating set for $A$.
I am able to prove that $A$ is group. But, for the generators part, I am thinking that each transformation is obtained by a translation (by $b$) and a dilation by $a$, but but when I use these two transformations I couldn't write $T$ by these two elements. I don't know if I did a mistake but I believe the argument and the basic idea is correct.

I am also thinking to visualize each transformation as a matrix and follow the idea of Mobius transformation, but not sure if this also works.

Comment: You need to be more precise about your generating set. For example, you could just take all of $A$ as a set of generators.

Comment: @AlexProvost I mean the smallest set with generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $T$ is isomorphic to the group of matrices
$$
G=
\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  a & b \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{array}%
\right),\ a,b\in F,\ a\neq0.
$$
If $F$ is a finite field, then this group is generated by two elements:
$$
g_1=\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  \alpha & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{array}%
\right),\
g_2=\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{array}%
\right),
$$
where $\alpha$ a primitive element of $F$.

Comment: so the generators are $u$ and $u+1$, right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @math_for_ever No, $T(u)=u$ cannot be in a minimal generating set since it's redundant. You mean $T_1(u)=\alpha u$ and $T_2(u)=u+1$ form a minimal generating set $\{T_1,T_2\}$, where $\alpha$ is a generator for $F^\times$.

Comment: but $1 \in F^{*}$ is a generator where $F=GF(8)$, or $3$ is a generator?

Comment: @math_for_ever I think you are misunderstanding something. It should be very clear that $1$ does not generate $F^\times$ multiplicatively. And since $GF(8)$ has the property that $1+1=0$, the element $3$ is just $3=1+1+1=1$, so you're still just talking about $1$. Are you mixing up $GF(8)$ with the integers mod $8$? Because those are different things.